# Oracle APEX and REST Data Services: No provider found for: requires oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.URLMapping

Tags: oracle-rest-data-services

I am trying to install APEX_230100 and ORDS 23.2 on FREEPDB1 on ol8 on docker on MacOS but without luck.
Both APEX and ORDS are installed successfully...

Now when firing up ords in standalone mode:

```
[oracle@81244fe391d1 ~]$ ords --debug --config /home/oracle/ordsconfig serve
CWD=/home/oracle
ORDS_HOME=/opt/oracle/ords
java -Doracle.dbtools.cmdline.home=/opt/oracle/ords -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dnashorn.args=--no-deprecation-warning -Doracle.dbtools.cmdline.ShellCommand=ords -Duser.timezone=UTC -agentlib
:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000 -jar /opt/oracle/ords/ords.war --verbose --config /home/oracle/ordsconfig serve
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
```

...and hitting, in a different terminal window:

```
open http://localhost:8080/ords
```

the browser window displays the message: `No provider found for: requires oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.URLMapping`

some log-lines:

```
2023-07-18T11:13:59.326Z SEVERE      <lsP2MLhRnJIfYk97hJvAeA> GET localhost /ords/_/landing?redirect=true 500 No provider found for:  requires oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.URLMapping
InternalServerException [statusCode=500, logLevel=SEVERE, reasons=[No provider found for:  requires oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.URLMapping]]
        at oracle.dbtools.http.errors.ServletResponseExceptionMapper.mapError(ServletResponseExceptionMapper.java:56)
Caused by: oracle.dbtools.plugin.api.types.TypeDependencyNotAvailableException: The service: (provides oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.URLMapping) is not available in the current scope
```

Is there any help out there?

Comment: This is more of a troubleshooting exercise than simple Q&A - please start a thread on our product/company forums https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/domain/dev-community/category/oracle_rest_data_services

Comment: Thank you @thatjeffsmith . I have started a thread here: https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/oracle-apex-and-rest-data-services-no-provider-found-for-re-6619

Comment: In my case the problem occured because I changed the sys or system password after configuring ords. Reverted the password back and it worked